# Is there any way to get repository insights via the GitHub Rest API v3

Tags: github, github-api, octokit, octokit.net

I want to get statistics for the number of issues opened/closed for a repository during a specified period of time. I can view this information in GitHub by clicking the insights tab.

For example: https://github.com/nodejs/node/pulse

Can I pull any of this information via the GitHub Rest API v3? I was looking through the documentation but couldn't find any information. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5):

You can use GitHub API V3 to search issues and PRs. For example, if I want to search all issues on the repo `nodejs/node` created for the duration `October 6, 2017 – October 13, 2017` 
you can make the following request - `https://api.github.com/search/issues?q=repo:nodejs/node+created:2017-10-06..2017-10-13`. 
From the JSON search response received you can determine those issues that result in PRs and its status.  Ref:[Search Issues](https://help.github.com/articles/searching-issues-and-pull-requests/)

Comment: This is the best option for now, and I don't know if this will land in the v4 GraphQL API any time soon...